# How to plot summaries of a table in bar chart

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I have a table of SNPs and the information about the corresponding gene: Gene ID, Gene type and Gene Name:

```
          SNP            Gene ID         Gene type      Gene Name
1    rs10876864 ENSG00000123411.10    protein_coding          IKZF4
2    rs10876864 ENSG00000123411.10    protein_coding          IKZF4
3    rs10876864 ENSG00000123411.10    protein_coding          IKZF4
4    rs10876864 ENSG00000123411.10    protein_coding          IKZF4
5   CNVR2845.57  ENSG00000196126.6    protein_coding       HLA-DRB1
6   CNVR2845.57  ENSG00000196126.6    protein_coding       HLA-DRB1
7   CNVR2845.57  ENSG00000196126.6    protein_coding       HLA-DRB1
8   CNVR2845.57  ENSG00000196126.6    protein_coding       HLA-DRB1
9     rs6030897  ENSG00000201372.1             snRNA             U6
10    rs6030897  ENSG00000201372.1             snRNA             U6
11    rs6030897  ENSG00000201372.1             snRNA             U6
```

I want to plot a bar chart of the total # of SNPs to see how many of the SNPs are protein_coding or snRNA or etc.

This is my code so far:

```
barplot(as.matrix(data1), main="SNP", xlab="Gene type", ylab= "Total SNP",     names.arg=c("protein_coding","snRNA","pseudogene","antisense","lincRNA",""), border="blue", density=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
```

But i'm getting an error saying:

```
Error in barplot.default(as.matrix(data1), main = "SNP", xlab = "Gene type",  :      incorrect number of names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In apply(height, 2L, cumsum) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In apply(height, 2L, cumsum) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In apply(height, 2L, cumsum) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In apply(height, 2L, cumsum) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you have four columns and you provide **5** `names.arg`
2. Same for density, but this alone wouldn't come up with an error...
3. the first item of `barplot`, called `height`, according to `?barplot` shall be:

   height
   either a vector or matrix of values describing the bars which make up the plot. If height is a vector, the plot consists of a sequence of rectangular bars **with heights given by the values in the vector**. If height is a matrix and beside is FALSE then each bar of the plot corresponds to a column of height, **with the values in the column giving the 
   heights** of stacked sub-bars making up the bar. If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, 
   then the values in each column are juxtaposed rather than stacked.

you have character columns, what did you expect :-) ? you need to do some summary statistics before plotting your data... something like

`barplot(table(df$Gene_type, df$SNP))`

but I would suggest to have a look at many other better ways and obviously at the `ggplot2` package which would be able to do that automatically.